# how to get a plain old external link working with featherlight

Tags: featherlight.js

I have a div with a link:

```
<div data-featherlight="test" >
  <a href = "http://example.com" target = "_blank">Link </a>
</div>
```

The lightbox works fine, but when I click the link, it makes a recursive lightbox.  I just want the link to pop to a new window.  Note, I don't want an ajax call, just a pop to a link on a 3rd party domain.

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, you might get closer to what you want by using a `iframe`? FL will think your link should be done with ajax, so you'll have to specify you want an iframe instead...